# Pdf to Json export using pdfminer.six python

Tags: python, json, parsing, pdf, pdfminer

i want to export text pdf to json using python pdfminer.six but when exported it gives the output in text. I want to save the text in a json format in a file.

thank you

Comment: That just means you have to convert it.  Does the PDF look anything like JSON data?

Comment: The text extracted looks exactly like the data inside the PDF. The pdfminer.six can only output text or html. 

When using stringify, it creates a json with word seperate element. However what I want is to have meaningful json with each line / section as seperate element. 

The resulting json will then be pushed to our api.

Comment: The tools don't know the structure of your document.  You will have to do the organization yourself.

Comment: How do I make the tool aware about the structure of the document ? How to basically to divide the document in sections and then get text from those sections as json.

Comment: YOU have to do it.  Take the text it's giving you and start processing it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Being a newbie, any guide I can follow to understand better and can help me process the data. Appreciate your time and guidance.

Comment: My advice when tackling a problem like this is always to think, how would I do this as a human?  If someone gave you a piece of paper with the output from pdfminer, knowing what you know about the original document, how would you go about dividing it up?  Are there patterns that separate the sections?  Are there columns separated by white space?

Comment: Yes absolutely, I can decipher the text, divide it myself into seperate fields manually. Mostly because I recognise the data instantly. 

So I guess it's all about find the right patterns and extracting the data from the output. 

Thank you so much for taking out the time to explain in such simple terms. Appreciate it.